# if-else condition: AND evaluation mystery

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I'm working on an app for Android. In my code I have the following lines:

```
if (shape != null && !created && isTap(touchDown, event)) {
    DrawPrimitive newShape = listener.onTouch(event, shape);
    if (newShape != shape)
        canvas.onDrawingChanged(true);
}
```

created is a boolean member. I'm wondering because created is true but the runtime steps into my if even without calling the isTap method. If I change the ! to the false comparsion, everything works fine.

```
if (shape != null && created == false && isTap(touchDown, event)) {
    DrawPrimitive newShape = listener.onTouch(event, shape);
    if (newShape != shape)
        canvas.onDrawingChanged(true);
}
```

So I'm wondering if the ! is not allowed. But even if so, why is my isTap method (in version one) not called and why is the inner code executed without evaluating all AND conditions.

Comment: How did you check whether it was called?

Comment: Try changing your code back to the first version and run it. I'm betting it will work fine.

Comment: How did I check? By debugging of course.

Comment: `!created` is correct style. As maybe @zmbq hinted, it might be old code being debugged. Please never use `==/!= false/true`.

Comment: Breakpoints sometimes don't work, at least for me. I have to restart Eclipse and restart the device sometimes to make it work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`!created` and `created == false` are equivalent.  The first version should behave in exactly the same way as the second.

Comment: The actual problem was that my created-member was of type Boolean (java.lang) instead of the lower-case boolean.

Comment: Ah right, then yes in that case, the object Boolean would not follow the same rules for equality and the `!` unary character

Answer (score 2):

Why `isTap()` isn't called: `&&` conjunctions (and `||` disjunctions for that matter) are evaluated with short-circuiting from left to right: when the left hand side operand of the expression evaluates to `false` (`true` for `||`), the right hand side operand does not need to be evaluated: the value of the expression is already known.

`!created` and `created == false` are the same in Java if `created` is `boolean`. If it's `Boolean`, you will have problems with autoboxing/unboxing:

- `!created` autounboxes the `Boolean` to `boolean` and complements the result with `!`.
- `created == false` autoboxes `false` boolean literal to `Boolean` and compares the object references. They aren't necessarily the same `Boolean` objects.

To avoid such problems and as a rule of thumb, don't use `true` or `false` directly in boolean expressions.

Comment: But then it should not jump into my inner code because the whole condition is false on the second condition.

Comment: How do you know? In question comments you say "debugging" but the debugger can confuse you by seemingly jumping to lines that are not executed. You can use logging for more clarity.